# Installing CiviCRM 4.6.11 on a Joomla 3.4.8

Tags: joomla, civicrm-home

I am trying to install CiviCRM 4.6.11 on a Joomla 3.4.8 website which I downloaded from the Joomla Extensions Directory. When I install it nothing happens.  I dont see any error message or a success message.  Joomla normally displays an error message when an installation is not successful. The website is on localhost.

I would appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM is likely much heavier then the average Joomla Extension. And because it runs behind more CMS-systems the preferred installation could be different then the usual Joomla Extension.

Please have a look at the "Installing CiviCRM for Joomla" page on the CiviCRM site and follow the instructions there for the best way to install CiviCRM for Joomla:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Joomla

Comment: Thanks so much.  The document "installing CiviCRM" was very useful and civiCRM is up and running.  I am playing on localhost and I dont have cPanel but I used "Profiles" and it worked like a bomb!

Comment: great, good luck with CiviCRM